# UITableView won't resize properly until I rotate device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am setting the frame of a UITableView in viewDidLoad, also after the device is rotated to ensure that it remains in the proper location. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setItemBoundaries];
}

- (void) setItemBoundaries {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        self.raceTable.frame = CGRectMake(20,502,728,472);
    }
    else {
        self.raceTable.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,492,708);
    }
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self setItemBoundaries];
}
```

However when the app loads, the table is sized incorrect (only on landscape mode): [image]

After rotating through portrait back to landscape, it looks fine: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the `-setItemBoundaries` into the `-viewWillAppear:` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // [self setItemBoundaries];
}
```

and:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self setItemBoundaries];
}
```

and *violá*...

Answer (score 0):

```
did...
```

...is called after the rotation has occurred, and therefore possibly after the table has been drawn.

Try,

```
willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
```

...to set the new boundaries before the table is redrawn.

Comment: ...he has written _after rotating through portrait back to landscape, it looks fine_, so why do you suggest him to change the working parts of the code?